# Battery level never gets 100%, but stays at 99%

Tags: power-management, battery

This is a new X1 carbon and it has been connected to power 6 hours, but it is still at 99%. It never seems to reach 100%, why?

```
$  upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                00HW029
  serial:               3119
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              tis 16 aug 2016 16:53:53 (59 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              55,03 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         55,52 Wh
    energy-full-design:  52,06 Wh
    energy-rate:         2,934 W
    voltage:             17,286 V
    percentage:          99%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a x1 carbon from 2015. They are designed this way..

If you unplug it and wait for it to go below 96% it should charge up to 100%.. The reason they do this is because it's bad for the battery with alot of small charges..

Your battery and system is working the way it should. Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

This (or similar effect) is common with new lithium batteries.  They're sold with a partial charge, from testing at the factory, and the charging circuit doesn't know how the actual capacity without some "experience" in watching the battery charge and discharge.  As you discharge the battery in normal use, the charging system watches the voltage and measures the amount of charge you're actually consuming; this lets it calculate the true capacity (which always varies a tiny bit from one cell to another, even with mass production).

After one or two discharge cycles and recharges, the charging circuits will be able to correctly report the charge percentage to your operating system, and your battery indicator will say 100% immediately after charge.  Also, any display with "minutes remaining" will be more accurate, because the charging system and software will be able to accurately estimate the running time based on actual current usage vs. voltage drop.